# Do background threads run slower than other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, windows-services, background-service

I have a C# console application running as a Windows Service. It implements `BackgroundService`, which is the [recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) to implement Windows services.

In addition, I'm using Hangfire to initiate my tasks.

I've noticed that a longer running tasks takes nearly 11 minutes, while the same task run on my local machine (not as a Windows service, not using `BackgroundService`, and in debug mode) takes less than 6 minutes.

Am I to assume that background threads generally run slower? Or are there likely other issues going on here?

The code itself performs a bunch of calculations on data from an SQL Server database and updates the data.

Comment: As far as I know, the only differences between a _background thread_ and one that's not are a) the state if the `IsBackground` property on the `Thread` object and b) the process will end when the last foreground thread ends - background threads don't count in that decision

Comment: Are you comparing time measurements made on the same machine, or on different machines?

Comment: Are you assuming that [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice)s run on [background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground) threads? Have you verified this assumption?

Comment: There's no possible way for anyone to provide an answer with the information that's been provided. If you didn't have so many points, this post would have been closed within the first two minutes of posting it.  Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Windows forms applications do get a foreground boost when active, and you can ask that other threads get the same boost (see [SetAdditionalForegroundBoost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setadditionalforegroundboostprocesses)). But this wouldn't apply to a console application unless you did something really strange.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Yes, I'm assuming they run on background threads because the name has *background* in it, and MS describes the tasks as background tasks. Yes, I'm comparing on two different computers. I can understand one might be faster, but I wouldn't expect twice as fast.

Comment: You have two unknown parameters in your comparison: different application types and different machines. You'll never get enough information for a valid conclusion this way. You have to reduce the parameters to one. Either test two different application types on the same machine, or the same application type on two different machines.

Comment: @JonathanWood - From experience I would expect up to an order of magnitude difference or more. So 10x wouldn't be out of the question. You're doing well if it's only 2x.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Threads run at their given priority, you can give a particular task a higher priority, which means that it will be executed before any threads of a lower priority.   A background thread can have a higher priority than other threads, and a UI thread can have a lower priority.

In practice, this doesn't really make much difference, as you probably have a multi-thread/core processor.

If you are accessing a database, your thread/task is probably waiting for the database server to reply (i/o bound operations).  Unless you are doing really complicated calculations (CPU bound operations) the thread is probably waiting for something external to happen, and that is outside your control.